# How to filter subdirectories based off the item count in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter folders based off of the count for the number of files in each folder.

I have been able to list the folder name and the value if there is a value greater than 1. I am trying to exclude the folders that may contain no items.

The amount of items changes daily.

```
$Date2 = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$Date2Str = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $Date2

$startFolder = "U:\test"

#Returns the Count of files in each queue
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object 
{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}  | Sort-Object) 

if($colItems -ine $null){

foreach ($i in $colItems)
 {
     $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Where-Object 
($_.CreationTime -lt $Date2Str -and $_.Name -like "*.tif"))
    $i.Name + " -- " -f ($subFolderItems.Count) |Format-Table 
@{Expression={$colItems -ge 1}}
```

I expect the output of $colItems to be the subFolder name, and the count, excluding any subFolder with a Count less than 1 or equals to 0.

The actual return is the list of subfolder Names and counts with all subFolders including those with a count equal to 0.

Comment: Do you specifically need to run this on PowerShell 2.0? (there are easier alternatives to the `$_.PsIsContainer` check in later versions)

Comment: I do not have a specific need for Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got your explanation right you're looking for something like this:

```
$startFolder = 'U:\test'

Get-ChildItem -Path $startFolder -Directory | 
Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = 'FileCount'; Expression = { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).count}}
```

That lists all subfolders of your `$startFolder` together with their file count.

BTW: This code expects at least Powershell version 3.

... and of course you can pipe this now to a `Where-Object` and output only the folders with more than one file in it ...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $startFolder -Directory | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = 'FileCount'; Expression = { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).count } } |
        Where-Object -Property FileCount -GT -Value 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was trying to accomplish. The only thing I changed was in the `Where-Object -Property FileCount -CGE -Value 1` . This allows for any instance when there are more than 1 file.